# Common pagination in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

How to create common pagination in AngularJs.
For example Can we create Factory OR Service and how to access it in controller?
Is it possible? Or otherwise we should keep seperate pagination for seperate controller?

Comment: Best to make it a directive (with it's own controller). Then you can simply use it as an element <pagination attr1="foo" attr2="bar"></pagination> etc

Answer (score 0):

For pagination:

1. Directive pagination can be used. 
   http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs
2. Smart table can be used with inbuilt pagination functionality. http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

There is no need to create service or factory.

There should be separate pagination for separate controller.
It depends on the data.